# Connection String clearly says do not use Integrated Security, but the error I'm getting implies it is

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I've got a connection string for my database, and it clearly states that it should be using a user id and password, and not integrated security.  On 1 machine it works great, but the same project and database `.mdf` file, I get this error:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "aspnet-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502" requested by the login.  The login failed.  Login failed for user "LAPTOP-8CHAURFC\matt"

I have nowhere in this project where I've specified to use this login.  No connection string that I can find that are using Integrated Security, etc.

Does anyone have any ideas on where to find some information on this?

Edit: So, this is interesting.  When I view the `DbContextOptions<CUSERSMDAWDYDOCUMENTSDAGMDFContext>` options in debug, it has an extensions array. The 2nd item has a `ConnectionString` property, and there I see the offending connection string.  I have no idea how this is being set or inferred.

[image]

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DAG2;User ID=bob2;Password=DAGissues;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: Have you tried explicitly stating `Trusted_Connection=False;`?

Comment: Good idea, but I just did and I got the same error.  I thought it was Integrated Security=False, but neither one work.  It's like it is doing something when creating the DB Context and it's pulling from some magical unspecified place.

Comment: Does the other database have SQL authentication enabled?

Comment: Not that I can tell.  See my recent edit.  Where the heck is that connection string with aspnet-whatever coming from?!!?!  If I search for it, it's not anywhere in my project or solution.

Comment: Can you connect with SQL Server management Studio?  If so your connection string has to match to SQL Instance in the login window of SSMS.  If the login window says Windows credentials than you must use Integrated Security is true.  A Sql Server can has both windows credentials and SQL Server credentials (username password) for both login and database.  If you can login to the server with SSMS change the log files in the explorer under Management to help debug issue.

Comment: I'll try to do what you say.  I've tracked it down to the fact, I think, that the call to Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection") is not returning my defined connection string.  Looks like Configuration has 6 providers.  Provider 0 is Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Chained(ConfigurationProvider), and that is what is returning the wrong connection string.  Provider 1 is for appsettings.json (Optional) and that one would likely return my correct connection string.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to MY database just fine via SSMS.  The problem is that it is looking for a DB that I don't think exists, and even if it does, it doesn't allow my windows login to connect. But it shouldn't even be TRYING to do that.  I can't find anywhere in any file that tells is that db is the one to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect using Integrated Security, it will try to use your Windows user account. That's what your response implies.  Look in the Security menu option for the Windows username.  Check the permissions for that user.

Also you cannot create databases in many cases using Integrated Security.

I would create a brand new application and test Integrated Security=True. Then I would change it to a new SQL user that I would create.